# How do i display complete log in terminal

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

[image]I have been banging my head around this one, I am trying to debug a nodejs application and my terminal is not displaying the entire list of errors, it is stuck at the top part as show in the image and I cannot scroll further up ?

Im on 14.04 mate if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your terminal, you could also enable "unlimited" scrollback. In GNOME Terminal (and presumably its MATE equivalent), select *Profile Preferences* in the *Edit* menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It also depends up the size of your log files,

Say if you have a bigger the log file in size, editor takes long time to load and that time scroll down key might not work.

First check the log files size, before you investigating it,

If size is the issue - you can use "tail" command to see last few lines of your log file.

```
tail myfile.log -n 100 // this will give you last 100 lines of your log file "100" can be replaced with the desire number.
```

If size of the log file is not your issue - you can use "shift + g" command to got to your end of the log file, after open that log with some text editor.

```
vi myfile.log
ctrl-f // scrolls down one screen
shift g place cursor on last line of text
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to read the output of some program you're running, not a log file...

You could redirect stderr to a logfile before running the program, then all error messges would be written to a logfile, something like this would tee stderr to a file and also leave it visible in the terminal (for "live" viewing if that's important):

```
errorlog=~/setup-errorlog.txt
exec 2> >(tee -a $errorlog >&2)
```

And redirecting stdout to a logfile would be the basic `command > file`

Then to view a big logfile, can use `less /var/log/syslog` for example. And could be combined with `grep` to just find interesting results, and/or piped to less or another file first.

It looks like your terminal window has run out of it's max scroll lines (scrollback), so the "unlimited scrollback" answer looks good too